# Must a series converge after a finite number of 'césaro mean' applications if it does after infinitely many.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\alpha=(\alpha_n)_{n\ge0}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $C(\alpha)=(\beta_n)_{n\ge0}$ where
$$\beta_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_k$$
Finally let $C^n=C\circ C^{n-1}$ with $C^0=\text{Id}$ be functions from the set of real sequences to itself.

Will the pointwise limit $C^{\infty}(\alpha)=\gamma$ always exist? Will it always be convergent (i.e. will $\lim_{n\to\infty}\gamma_n$ exist)?

I also want to know, if the pointwise limit sequence $C^{\infty}(\alpha)$ **does exist and is convergent**, must there be a finite *n* such that the sequence $C^n(\alpha)$ is convergent? Certainly conversely if this sequence is convergent at a finite *n* then it is convergent for all greater values of *n* and so if the pointwise limit exists its limit will be the same value.

Comment: What did you try? Did you try $a_n=2^n$ or $a_n=2^{2^n}$?

Comment: You will find that the iterates $C^n(\alpha)$ put more and more emphasis on the early terms of the sequence.  Thus $C^\infty(\alpha)$ will be the constant sequence $(\alpha_0)$.